# Different config file for different languages in Symfony2/3

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony

I want to load differents config files for each language in my Symfony app, like that:

AppKernel.php

```
...
$loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/locale/'.$lang.'.'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
```

config/locale/en_US.prod.yml

```
parameters:
  locale: en_US
imports:
  - { resource: ../config_prod.yml }
```

config/locale/es_ES.prod.yml

```
parameters:
  locale: es_ES
imports:
  - { resource: ../config_prod.yml }
```

But when I load for the first time, I think Symfony is caching the config file, and always have the same locale in the differents domains. (.com .fr .es etc)

There is a another way to do the same? Thanks!

Comment: It's only for setting the locale or there are another configuration values dependent on the locale? What are they?

Comment: @Edu is for more configuration values. Social network links, validation codes, etc...

Comment: I don't now if it is the better way, but we solve this situation with a listener